# OrderBy / ThenBy looping - nested Lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested list,

```
List<List<String>> intable;
```

where I would like to sort all the columns. The problem is that the number of columns depends on user input.

Sorting the list like this works fine (assuming 4 columns for this example)

```
var tmp = intable.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[1]);
tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[2]);
tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[3]);
intable = tmp.ToList();
```

But, when I put it in a loop, like this:

```
var tmp = intable.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
        tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[i]);
}
intable = tmp.ToList();
```

it no longer works correctly, and sorts only the fourth column.

Comment: See this [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/61e502b4-6795-4e51-b70e-2be642cfc413/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/61e502b4-6795-4e51-b70e-2be642cfc413/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a case of *access to a modified closure*. Change the code to this and it will work:

```
var tmp = intable.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var thisI = i;
    tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[thisI]);
}
intable = tmp.ToList();
```

Eric Lippert has written a [two-part article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) describing the problem. The reason it doesn't work as you expect to is - in short - because LINQ is only using the last value of `i` when it is evaluated when you call `ToList()`. It's the same as if you had written:

```
var tmp = intable.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[3]);
tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[3]);
tmp = tmp.ThenBy(x => x[3]);
intable = tmp.ToList();
```

Comment: Eric Lippert did confirm that the closure behavior will change in C# 5. [SO Link Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8899347/498969)

Comment: @AdamSpicer: It will not change for "for" loops, just for "foreach" loops.

Comment: I was trying to do just this and this answer was tremendously helpful. In my case I had several variables that needed to be re-declared (or whatever you call it) inside the loop to be correctly accessible in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a comparer

```
class StringListComparer : IComparer<List<string>>
{
    public int Compare(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        int minLength = Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
            int comp = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
        }
        return x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);
    }
}
```

then sort the list like this

```
intable.Sort(new StringListComparer());
```