# C# Sort List of char arrays using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort the following List 
`List<char[]> permutations = new List<char[]>();`

it contains all the permutations of the number 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 however they are not sorted but I need them sorted. This is what I did to fix my problem :

```
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[9]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[8]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[7]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[6]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[5]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[4]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[3]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[2]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[1]).ToList();
        permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[0]).ToList();
```

how can I avoid this or how can this be written in 1 line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would note that you are re-sorting the list 9 times.

The *proper* way to chain orderings is to use `ThenBy` (note that the order of comparisons is reversed to get the results to order in the same manner that you have now):

```
    permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[0])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[1])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[2])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[3])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[4])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[5])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[6])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[7])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[8])
                               .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[9]).ToList();
```

One simple way to reduce the amount of *code* is

```
permutations = permutations.OrderBy(a => new string(a)).ToList();
```

Or to just order the list in-place.

```
permutations.Sort((a1, a2) => (new string(a)).CompareTo(new string(a2)));
```

Granted those generate a lot of strings, but the next best option is to write an `IComparer<char[]>` that compares two character arrays the way you want it to.  One other option (since I know that the list of character arrays came from a different question) would by so store the permutations as *strings* instead of *arrays*.  Then sorting is a no-brainer:

```
permutations.Sort();
```

Comment: Great answer. Just a few notes :
OrderBy(a => new string(a)).ToList() && .Sort((a1, a2) => (new string(a1)).CompareTo(new string(a2))); are really slow in performence compared to the .ThenBy method,also the permutations.Sort(); wont work if we are using chars since we don't provide IComparer to it. The first one is almost 4 times faster than the second and the third

Comment: 1) That's why I said it was a way to reduce _code_.  I'm not surprised it's slower just because of the amount of memory allocated for those strings. Whether or not that's a _problem_ depends on the overall performance of the system.

Comment: 2)  If you stored strings instead of character arrays then you wouldn't need to pass a comparer to `Sort` - it will sort the strings alphabetically be default.  It doesn't work for character arrays since there's not a "default" comparer for char arrays.

Comment: nice, the original way could be simplified using a foreach: instead of 10 lines......var order = permutations.OrderBy(e=> e[0]);
      
      for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) order = order.ThenBy(e=> e[i]);
      
      var final = order.ToList(); just need to fix the closure :P

Comment: i will be captured this way (closure) so it will look like this `            var order = permutations.OrderBy(e => e[0]); for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                var i1 = i;
                order = order.ThenBy(e => e[i1]);
            }
            var final = order.ToList();`

Comment: @KOPEUE I would see how much faster it is to store the permutations as strings instead of char arrays - I bet it's faster _and_ cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but I was working on this and have a solution that is suggested in comments but not shown. As suggested by [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762320/george), the dynamic way to handle this is to use a for loop but there is one gotcha as noted here [OrderBy / ThenBy in Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038007/orderby-thenby-looping-nested-lists-in-c-sharp).

This is much faster than converting each char[] to a string as noted in the other comments and answers.

```
var p = permutations.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    var index = i; //Must do this to Avoid Gotcha
    p = p.ThenBy(x => x[index]);
}
permutations = p.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `string` instead of `char[]` which is basically `IEnumerable<char>`
In this way you can simply write

```
permutations.Sort();
```

if you want to keep it your way you can chain your expressions like:

```
permutations = permutations.OrderBy(arr1 => arr1[9])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[8])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[7])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[6])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[5])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[4])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[3])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[2])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[1])
    .ThenBy(arr1 => arr1[0])
    .ToList();
```