# What is the for/while equivalent of foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a `foreach` loop that needs converting to a `for` or `while` loop. My loop looks like this:

```
foreach (Item item in Items)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

What is the equivalent `for` or `while` loop?

I think I need to use `GetEnumerator` to get an `IEnumerator<Item>`, but I don't know how to use it properly. `Items` isn't a list, otherwise I'd use indexing.

Comment: is there any particular reason for why you need to convert it?

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso I need do extra stuff that won't work in a `foreach`, so I need to know how to use GetEnumerator.

Comment: @KendallFrey: What stuff out of interest and will it work with an enumerator? You might be best off jsut doing what Ryan suggested in his (now deleted) answer and just using the count to loop.

Comment: If we come to perfect replacement it just may be so perfect that it does have the same drawback that you wanted to surpass in the first place. So what is the original drawback?

Comment: @KendallFrey why don't you use the Count() method  then in the classic for each and access the item by index? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not to sound thick, but if you can't do something within the standard `foreach` construct, how will expanding it out to the form using `GetEnumerator` be any better?

Comment: Okay, I lied. I don't need the exact same code. But if I know how to write the for loop, I know how to write my code to requirements.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso 1) Not every enumerable supports indexing 2) Not every enumerable supports multiple evaluations.

Comment: There are some uses for manual enumeration. For example implementing `Enumerable.Zip` without it is ugly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the simplest case(no disposing etc.) you can use:

```
var enumerator = Items.GetEnumerator();// `var` to take advantage of more specific return type
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  Item item = enumerator.Current;
  ...
}
```

For the exact rules check the C# specification 8.8.4 The foreach statement.

> A foreach statement of the form
>
> ```
> foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
> ```
>
> is then expanded to:
>
> ```
> {
>   E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
>   try {
>      V v;
>      while (e.MoveNext()) {
>         v = (V)(T)e.Current;
>                 embedded-statement
>     }
>   }
>   finally {
>      … // Dispose e
>   }
> ```
>
> }

*(Quoted from the C# Language Specification Version 4.0)*

The types using here are: "a collection type `C`, enumerator type `E` and element type `T`". `E` is the return type of `GetEnumerator`, and not necessarily `IEnumerator<V>` since `foreach` uses duck typing. The spec also describes a number of corner cases and how to infer these types, but those details are probably not relevant here.

In C# 5 the declaration of `v` will be moved into the `while` loop to get more intuitive closure semantics.

Comment: The change made in C# 5.0 is explained here, in case anyone missed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach/8899347#8899347

Comment: Can you explain the types/variables `E`, `C` and `T`? They don't come from the original `foreach`.

Comment: `E` is the enumerator, `C` the collection type and `T` the element type.

Comment: Great. I understand `E` and `T`, but I don't get why `((C)(x))` is any different than `(x)`.

Comment: I think that's for the case where there is no `GetEnumerator` method, but `IEnumerator<T>.GetEnumerator` was implemented explicitly. The casts to `T` and `C` are just technicalities related to corner cases. The cast to `V` on the other hand is a clearly visible effect: `foreach` looks at explicit conversions from `T` to `V`, and not just implicit conversions.

Comment: I hope that when they make the change in C# 5.0, that it matches the specification outlined in the C# 5.0 book that Jon Skeet has already written :) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9174/193560

Comment: The use of `Dispose` should be considered required, not optional, except in cases where the concrete type of the enumerator is *known* not to require it.  Some iterators may behave badly if `Dispose` is not called.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use a `for` loop, it generally means there's some way of quickly accessing the n-th item (usually an indexer).

```
for(int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
{
  Item item = Items[i]; //or Items.Get(i) or whatever method is relevant.
  //...
}
```

If you're just going to access the iterator, you *usually* just want to use a `foreach` loop.  If, however, you can't, this is usually the model that makes sense:

```
using(IEnumerator<Item> iterator = Items.GetEnumerator())
while(iterator.MoveNext())
{
  Item item = iterator.Current;
  //do stuff
}
```

you could, technically, do this in a `for` loop, but it would be harder because the construct just doesn't align well with this format.  If you were to discuss the reason that you can't use a `foreach` loop we may be able to help you find the best solution, whether or not that involves using a `for` loop or not.

Comment: Correct use of an enumerator requires calling `IDisposable` upon it before abandoning it, unless the *concrete type* of the enumerator is known not to require cleanup.

Comment: @supercat Which is why I wrap the iterator in a `using` block, which properly disposes of it...

Answer (score 2):

This is an equivalent in a for-loop

```
for (IEnumerator i = Items.GetEnumerator(); i.MoveNext(); )
{
    Item item = (Item)i.Current;
    // some stuff
}
```

Comment: If you don't call MoveNext first, accessing Current will throw an InvalidArgumentException.  It doesn't skip anything for me.

Comment: @AustinSalonen I tried it, and it worked. Yours creates an extra item.

Comment: @AustinSalonen It doesn't. I just tested it.

Comment: The above neglects to call `Dispose` on the enumerator.  While there are some enumerator types which do not implement `IDisposable`, one should call `IDisposable.Dispose` on an enumerator unless one knows that the *concrete type* of the enumerator does not require cleanup.