# Print a star (*) right triangle in C#

Tags: c#

I have already done this with a nested for loop but, I also want to know how to do this with a while loop. I already have this

```
 int j = 10;
     int k = 0;
     while (j > 0)
     {
        if (k <= j)
        {
           Console.Write("* ");
           Console.WriteLine();
        }
        j--;
     } Console.WriteLine();
```

and it prints out a line of stars(*). I know the inner loop has to refer to the outer loop but I'm not sure how to do this in a while statement.

Comment: @mechanicalsnail Thanks for the read.  I'll now join the posse to end all homework tags!

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how the inner loop refers to the outer loop? You said you have already done this with a nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does produce something resembling a triangle:

```
int x = 1;
int j = 10;
int k = 0;
while (j > 0)
{
    if (k <= j)
    {
       Console.Write("* ");
    }
    if (j >= 1)
    {
        int temp = x;
        while (temp >= 0)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            temp--;
        }
        x = x + 1;
        Console.Write("*");

     }
       Console.WriteLine();
       j--;
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
   double f = Math.Round(x * 1.5);
   while (f != 0)
   {
      Console.Write("*");
      f--;
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this has already been done using nested for-loops, then conversion to while-loops is straight forward. (If using the *same algorithm*, 2 for-loops will result in 2 while-loops, not 1.)

This [for-loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx):

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator) {
    body;
}
```

Is equivalent to this while-loop:

```
initializer;
while (condition) {
    body;
    iterator;
}
```

---

<del>Nit: There is actually [a breaking change in C# 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899347/166390) with respect to the variable lifetimes making the above ever-so-not-quite-identical (in C# 5+), but that is another topic for a language specification not yet finalized and only affects variables bound in closures.</del>

Comment: The breaking change you reference is with respect to `foreach` loops, not `for` or `while` loops.

Comment: @Servy Ahh, thanks. For some reason I thought it was going to cover the entire loop family.

Answer (score 3):

for loops are trivially interchangeable with while loops.

```
// Height and width of the triangle
var h = 8;
var w = 30;

// The iterator variables
var y = 1;
var x = 1;

// Print the tip of the triangle
Console.WriteLine("*");

y = 1;
while (y++ <h) {
    // Print the bit of left wall
    Console.Write("*");

    // Calculate length at this y-coordinate
    var l = (int) w*y/h;

    // Print the hypothenus bit
    x = 1;
    while (x++ <l-3) {
            Console.Write(" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("*");
}

// Now print the bottom edge
x = 0;
while (x++ <w) {
    Console.Write("*");
}
```

Output:

```
*
*   *
*       *
*           *
*              *
*                  *
*                      *
*                          *
******************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class x
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j;
            for ( i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    Console.Write("*");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

    }
```