# How to save multiple linq queries from a loop in a single variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I thought its possible to save multiple linq queries from a loop in a single variable ?

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string ActiveUserId = (string)Session["ActiveUserGuid"];
        Guid MyGuid = new Guid(ActiveUserId);

        var queryRoots = from r in db.Roots
                         where r.UserId == MyGuid
                         select r.TaskId;

//Here is the questionable Part
        foreach (var i in queryRoots)
        {             
            var queryAllTasks = from t in db.Tasks
                                join b in db.Trees on t.TaskId equals b.ChildId
                                where b.TaskId == i
                                select t;
            tasksForView.Add(queryAllTasks); <---????? obviously doesnt work
        };

        return View(queryAllTasks);
    }

public class Root
{
    public int RootId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }  //navigation Property

    public int TaskId { get; set; } // composite key
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Tree Tree { get; set; } //navigation Property
}

public class Tree
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; } //Path length

    public virtual ICollection<Root> Roots { get; set; }

}
```

In case you are wondering what its supposed to do. I want to query several subtrees from a hierarchical transitiv closure table and return them to a view.

I know my code is not close to working and I just tried very simple solutions!
I guess a different way to do the query would get rid of the problem all together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Contains` on your integer list:

```
var tasks = 
    from t in db.Tasks
    join b in db.Trees on t.TaskId equals b.ChildId
    where queryRoots.Contains(b.TaskId)
    select t;

return View(tasks);
```

or do it all in one query:

```
var tasks = 
    from t in db.Tasks
    join b in db.Trees on t.TaskId equals b.ChildId
    join r in db.Roots on r.TaskId equals b.TaskId
    where r.UserId == MyGuid
    select t;

return View(tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're [closing over the loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach).  LINQ queries use deferred execution whenever possible, so you're just defining what the query is and storing that, not calculating the results and storing them.

You have a few choices here.  You could just add a `ToList` to the end of the query; it would eagerly evaluate it, and storing that list won't lead to problems.

What's likely breaking is that your query is using `i`, which is changed in the loop.  Since the query doesn't actually evaluate what `i` is until after the end of the loop, `i` will always have whatever the last value was.  This is easily fixed by just adding a new local variable inside of the loop and assigning `i` to it.  Use that local variable in your query.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `queryAllTasks` has deferred execution in each iteration of the loop. So all you're storing is an `IQueryable`.

What you want is

```
tasksForView.Add(queryAllTasks.ToList());
```

Also, I noticed you're trying to return `queryAllTasks` as your view model, but that variable is scoped to the for loop. I assume you want to return `tasksForView` as your model (which I further assume is declared elsewhere, as I don't see a declaration for it in the code you provided.)

Comment: I still need to read up on things and not just to fill gaps. Thank you for your explanation and steering me to the right topics.