# How to Invoke the Thread in a for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

Hi I want to pass sleeptime and the Thread Object to a method and call the method in a for loop. 
Pls see the code below

```
public delegate void PasParamsToThrdFunc(int integer, object obj2);
class Program
{
    Thread[] newThread=new Thread[10];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pr = new Program();
        pr.ThreadDeclaration();
        Console.Read();
    }

    public void ThreadDeclaration()
    {
        int time = 5000;
        for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
        {
            time = time * i;
            string s = i.ToString();
            ThreadStart starter = () => PasParamsToThrdFunc(time, newThread[i]);
            newThread[i] = new Thread(starter);
            newThread[i].Name = i.ToString();
            newThread[i].Start();
        }

    }

    public void PasParamsToThrdFunc(int waitTime, Thread obj)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
        Console.WriteLine("" + waitTime + " seconds completed and method is called for thread"+obj.Name+"");
        obj.Abort();
    }
  }
```

I want the 1st thread to be invoked after 5 seconds and shall kill the object and shall do the same for the 2nd thread and kill it at 10 seconds.
Please help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems more reasonable to use a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Anand Patel... There will always be a technology which is new.. This is new to me.. So dont think its a school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

1- when you pass `newThread[i]` to `PasParamsToThrdFunc` it is null. Change it to `i`

2- You may need to avoid [*closing* over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach) variables `i` and `time`

```
public void ThreadDeclaration()
{
    int time = 5000;
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int J = i; // <----
        int timez = time * i; // <----
        string s = i.ToString();

        ThreadStart starter = () => PasParamsToThrdFunc(timez, J);
        newThread[i] = new Thread(starter);
        newThread[i].Name = i.ToString();
        newThread[i].Start(); 
    }

}

public void PasParamsToThrdFunc(int waitTime, int i )
{
    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
    Console.WriteLine("" + waitTime + " seconds completed and method is called for thread" + newThread[i].Name + "");
    newThread[i].Abort(); // <-- No need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems I can see:

- You are accessing modified closures with the parameters you are passing to the thread function (you shouldn't modify those params after passing them).
- You passing a thread's handle to itself and then using it to abort itself. No need to do that, since it will just exit when after the sleep.
- You are calculating time incorrectly, by multiplying itself by i on each iteration, rather than using the time interval * i.

Try something like this instead:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pr = new Program();
            pr.ThreadDeclaration();
            Console.Read();
        }

        public void ThreadDeclaration()
        {
            int timeInterval = 5000;

            for (int i=1; i<3; i++)
            {
                int time = timeInterval * i;
                ThreadStart starter = () => PasParamsToThrdFunc(time);
                var thread = new Thread(starter) {Name = i.ToString()};
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        public void PasParamsToThrdFunc(int waitTime)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
            Console.WriteLine("" + waitTime + " seconds completed and method is called for thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        }
    }
}
```