# C# Action in Foreach

Tags: c#, delegates, foreach, action

`fMethod` is an `Action<Fruit>`.

But when `fMethod` is called, the parameter is always the last entry of `_Fruits`.
How to solve this?

```
foreach(Fruit f in _Fruits)
{
   field.Add(new Element(f.ToString(),delegate{fMethod(f);}));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a well-known problem of using a modified clause in a call that creates a delegate. Adding a temporary variable should solve it:

```
foreach(Fruit f in _Fruits)
{
    Fruit tmp = f;
    field.Add(new Element(f.ToString(),delegate{fMethod(tmp);}));
}
```

This problem is fixed in C# 5 ([see Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)).

Comment: This issue **is** fixed in C# 5.0:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster That's very nice to know, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a temp variable.

```
foreach(Fruit f in _Fruits)
{
   var temp = f;
   field.Add(new Element(temp.ToString(),delegate{fMethod(temp);}));
}
```