# When I use threads to print things to the console, why does it produce odd results?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I've been getting into Threads lately while reading the very nice pdf from Rob Miles ([here](http://www.csharpcourse.com/)). He had an example on page 160 (2012, C# pdf) but it didn't write to the console just did empty loops.

I wrote a very simple thread producing loop that creates 10 threads that are writing their IDs to the screen on each multiple of 1000.  This was nice - it showed me how threads were running together.  My Questions begins with why is my output so confused?  Often when I run the program below, I get multiple "Thread 3 Finished" lines where I'm pretty certain, I should only have one of each.

I added a ["lock"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from MSDN to the loop but it still seems to produce odd output (I'll put an example below).

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static object sync = new object();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread myThread = new Thread(() => DoThis(i));
                    myThread.Start();
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            static void DoThis(int s)
            {
                lock (sync) // a new addition that hasn't helped
                {
                    for (long j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
                    {
                        if (j % 1000 == 0) Console.Write(String.Format("{0}.", s));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nThread {0} Finished", s);
                    Debug.Print("\r\nThread {0} Finished", s); //<-- added to debug

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought I was doing okay - I have local variables (my counting loop), I have an int that is passed presumably not by reference and later I tried to lock it while doing it's loop.  No joy.What would I need to do to make the output look sensible?  I tried Deubg.Print to troubleshoot but it has errors too (below).

Eventually, I want to use threading in a larger application but if I can't get it right here, I'm not sure I want to!

Example Output from the debug.print line at the end: (note the multiples) ...

> ```
> Thread 1 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x15cc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 9 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x1d0c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 6 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x2248) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 10 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x22bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 9 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x85c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 9 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x1628) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 3 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x2384) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> Thread 6 Done
>
> Thread 2 Done
>
> Thread 4 Done
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x2348) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x2420) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread '<No Name>' (0x1ea8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> ```

Let me know if I can offer any more info on what I've tried.

Comment: I think your variable in the loop is captured. Store i in a temporary variable. But if you mean why the output is not ordered.. the execution of a thread is not guaranteed to be in the order it was started.

Comment: not worried about the exact order but it looks as if @MatthewWatson has answered given the same answer ... thankyou.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Captured Variable In Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are using a "modified closure" on the loop variable.

Although this has been fixed for `foreach` loops, `for` loops still have the issue (and always will)

To fix it, change your Main() to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int copy = i; // Make a copy of i to prevent the "modified closure" problem.
        Thread myThread = new Thread(() => DoThis(copy));
        myThread.Start();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

See here for more details:

[Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure)

[Eric Lippert's Article on Closures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Okay, I was looking suspiciously at that "i" ... Let me have a quick play.

Comment: @IV4 The closure thing hasn't changed for `for` loops, only for `foreach` loops. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264289/captured-closure-loop-variable-in-c-sharp-5-0

Comment: @I4V It's the same with .NET 4.5 and C# 5. The loop `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Thread myThread = new Thread(() => DoThis(i)); myThread.Start(); }` has the variable `i` as an "outer" variable, just like it had been `int i; /* declared before loop */ for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Thread myThread = new Thread(() => DoThis(i)); myThread.Start(); }`.

Comment: ... however, had he used `foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)) { Thread myThread = new Thread(() => DoThis(i)); myThread.Start(); }`, it would have depended on the version of C# he used.

Comment: Thank you all! - would seem I just needed to know what to search for!  I can see threads being a very interesting challenge.

Comment: @Sisyphus You know the same thing happens if you use just one thread? You can try this: `var actions = new List<Action>(); for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { actions.Add(() => DoThis(i)); } Console.WriteLine("After for loop! How many 'i' have been captured, ten or one? Invoking all actions sequentially:"); foreach (var a in actions) { a(); }` So this is more a matter of understanding what happens if an anonymous function (like a lambda `=>`) refers a local variable that later changes.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `Parallel.For` instead of starting threads yourself in a loop:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, DoThis);
```

If you needed to pass an extra argument (say `w`) as part of that, then you can do this:

```
var w = 4;
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => DoThis(i, w));
```

The other thing to consider of course is that the `Console` object is exclusive. If you use it from one thread, any other threads that try to use it will be blocked until it's finished with.

Also your `lock (sync)` is going to stop any two threads from doing their operation at the same time.

Bear in mind that your threads are not guaranteed to execute in any particular order.

Comment: I don't really mind what order - the lock was me trying to figure out what was going wrong!  I've never used Parallel.For (and many, many other things) so will have a quick read.

Comment: can I still pass a variable to the Dothis method?

Comment: `Parallel.For` passes the index (0..9) as the parameter to `Dothis` - `Dothis` happens to match the delegate type its expecting so what I've given you there should 'just work'

Comment: Right you are ... just while I've got you "on the hook", how would you modify this if my method was DoWork(int s, int w){...} ?

Comment: Cool, thanks - simple now that I see it.  I'd give you another upvote if I could!