# Captured Closure (for Loop Variable) in Go

Tags: for-loop, go, closures

> 2023 Sep Update: Read [Fixing For Loops in Go 1.22](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview)

Shouldn't Go compiler capture `for...range` loop variables as a locally assigned closure variable?

Long Version:

This caused me some confusion [in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264289/captured-closure-loop-variable-in-c-sharp-5-0) too and I was trying to understand it; that why it is fixed in C# 5.0 `foreach` (reason: the loop variable **can not** change inside the body of loop) and the reasoning for not fixing it in C# `for` loops (reason: the loop variable **can** change inside the body of loop).

Now (to me) `for...range` loops in Go seems pretty much like `foreach` loops in C#, but despite the fact that we can not alter those variables (like `k` and `v` in `for k, v := range m { ... }`); still we have to copy them to some local closures first, for them to behave as expected.

What is the reasoning behind this? (I suspect it's because Go treats any `for` loop the same way; but I'm not sure).

Here is some code to examine described behavior:

```
func main() {
    lab1() // captured closure is not what is expected
    fmt.Println(" ")

    lab2() // captured closure is not what is expected
    fmt.Println(" ")

    lab3() // captured closure behaves ok
    fmt.Println(" ")
}

func lab3() {
    m := make(map[int32]int32)
    var i int32
    for i = 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        m[i] = i
    }

    l := [](func() (int32, int32)){}
    for k, v := range m {
        kLocal, vLocal := k, v // (C) captures just the right values assigned to k and v
        l = append(l, func() (int32, int32) {
            return kLocal, vLocal
        })
    }

    for _, x := range l {
        k, v := x()
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}

func lab2() {
    m := make(map[int32]int32)
    var i int32
    for i = 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        m[i] = i
    }

    l := [](func() (int32, int32)){}
    for k, v := range m {
        l = append(l, func() (int32, int32) {
            kLocal, vLocal := k, v // (B) captures just the last values assigned to k and v from the range
            return kLocal, vLocal
        })
    }

    for _, x := range l {
        k, v := x()
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}

func lab1() {
    m := make(map[int32]int32)
    var i int32
    for i = 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        m[i] = i
    }

    l := [](func() (int32, int32)){}
    for k, v := range m {
        l = append(l, func() (int32, int32) { return k, v }) // (A) captures just the last values assigned to k and v from the range
    }

    for _, x := range l {
        k, v := x()
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

As it is shown in `lab1`, at the comment `// (A)` we get just the last values from the `range`; the output is like printing `9,9` ten times instead of showing expected result like `1,1`, `2,2`, ... (and of-course maps are not necessarily sorted in Go so we may see `3,3` ten times as the last pair of values; instead of `10,10` ten times as the last pair of values). The same goes for code at comment `// (B)` at `lab2`, which was expected because we are trying to capture outer variables inside the inner scope (I put this one too just to try that). In `lab3` at code at comment `// (C)` everything works fine and you will see ten pairs of numbers there like `1,1`, `2,2`, ....

I was trying to use **closure+function** as a replacement for **tuple**s in Go.

Comment: This is a FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: Besides @dyoo's Link, there is [Common Mistakes: Using goroutines on loop iterator variables](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you want the closure over the variable or the value? For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func VariableLoop() {
    f := make([]func(), 3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        // closure over variable i
        f[i] = func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("VariableLoop")
    for _, f := range f {
        f()
    }
}

func ValueLoop() {
    f := make([]func(), 3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        i := i
        // closure over value of i
        f[i] = func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("ValueLoop")
    for _, f := range f {
        f()
    }
}

func VariableRange() {
    f := make([]func(), 3)
    for i := range f {
        // closure over variable i
        f[i] = func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("VariableRange")
    for _, f := range f {
        f()
    }
}

func ValueRange() {
    f := make([]func(), 3)
    for i := range f {
        i := i
        // closure over value of i
        f[i] = func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("ValueRange")
    for _, f := range f {
        f()
    }
}

func main() {
    VariableLoop()
    ValueLoop()
    VariableRange()
    ValueRange()
}
```

Output:

```
VariableLoop
3
3
3
ValueLoop
0
1
2
VariableRange
2
2
2
ValueRange
0
1
2
```

References:

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)
>
> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.
>
> [Go FAQ: What happens with closures running as goroutines?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)
>
> To bind the current value of v to each closure as it is launched, one
>   must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration.
>   One way is to pass the variable as an argument to the closure.
>
> Even easier is just to create a new variable, using a declaration
>   style that may seem odd but works fine in Go.

Comment: closure over variable in `for` loops; closure over value in `for...range` loops.

Comment: An alternative to `i := i` I've seen the Go folks use is making the inner function take `i` as an argument. As to whether it should work this way, like all sorts of design questions, it's arguable, but when you buy into a language ecosystem you've got to work with what you have.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian: Your choice. See my revised answer. Use `k, v := k, v` for `range` in your example.

Comment: @twotwotwo You are absolutely right about ecosystem. But it was admittedly not a good choice in C#; and they've fixed it. I just want to know the reason (like even this is not possible because of Go compiler internals or the like) and as I've learnt from googling around it's been there for some time.

Comment: Ahh, interesting question. Maybe designers just find it easier (or cleaner?) for all loop variables to be treated as a single variable declared outside the scope for capturing purposes. Python is this way (`[lambda: i for i in range(10)][0]()` prints `9`); Perl, surprisingly, is not (`my @subs; for my $i (1..10) { push @subs, sub { print "$i"; } }; $subs[0]->()` prints `1`).

Comment: @KavehShahbazian: There is no correct semantics: [Differences_in_semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29#Differences_in_semantics). Anyway, it's not going to change in Go 1: [Go 1 and the Future of Go Programs](http://golang.org/doc/go1compat). You can easily obtain whatever behavior you want.

Comment: @peterSO You are right, there is no correct semantics. But there are surprising semantics in every PL that one should be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

The [Common Mistake / Using reference to loop iterator variable](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes) wiki page document your process (copy the loop variable into a new variable)

But the proposal [# 60078 `spec`: less error-prone loop variable scoping](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60078), May 2023, seek to address that.

And it is detailed in the Sept. 2023 blog post [Fixing For Loops in Go 1.22](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview).

> Changing the loop semantics would in essence insert this kind of `v := v` statement for every for loop variable declared with `:=`. It would fix this loop and many others to do what the author clearly intends.
>
> the new loop semantics would only apply in Go modules that have opted in to the release with the new loops. If that was Go 1.22, then only packages in a module with a `go.mod` that says go 1.22 would get the new loop semantics.

You can see the [design being considered here](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/60078-loopvar.md):

> This proposal is about changing for loop variable scoping semantics, so that loop variables are per-iteration instead of per-loop.

The [For statements with `for` clause](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_clause) would include:

> The `init` statement may be a short variable declaration (`:=`), but the post statement must not.
> Each iteration has its own separate declared variable (or variables).
>
> - The variable used by the first iteration is declared by the `init` statement.
> - The variable used by each subsequent iteration is declared implicitly before executing the post statement and initialized to the value of the previous iteration's variable at that moment.
>
> ```golang
> var prints []func()
> for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
>     prints = append(prints, func() { println(i) })
> }
> for _, p := range prints {
>     p()
> }
>
> // Output:
> // 0
> // 1
> // 2
> ```

---

Since [Go 1.21 is released](https://go.dev/doc/go1.21), [Russ Cox adds](https://60078)

> For anyone new to this issue and exploring what the change would mean, the Go playground now lets you experiment with the new semantics.
>
> To do that, use Go 1.21 and add `// GOEXPERIMENT=loopvar` at the top of your program.
>
> For example try https://go.dev/play/p/lDFLrPOcdz3 and then try deleting the comment.

```golang
// GOEXPERIMENT=loopvar

package main

func main() {
    var prints []func()
    for i := range make([]int, 5) {
        prints = append(prints, func() { println(i) })
    }
    for _, p := range prints {
        p()
    }
}
```

Output (with comment):

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Output (without comment):

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

---

Oct. 2023: [CL 532580](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/532580):

> This change causes the SSA builder to consult the GoVersion applicable to a range declaration.
> If the version is >=go1.21, then the new vars declared by "`for k, v := range x`" are created inside the loop anew on each iteration, not once
> before the loop.

[Test](https://go.googlesource.com/tools/+/4396a0beca8411e7c59868f220a7ca028842d4af/go/ssa/interp/testdata/rangevar.go) and [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XqZhfKv5BYj):

```golang
package main
// Test of new loop var semantics (#60078).
// (Try playing with https://go.dev/play/p/XqZhfKv5BYj,
// with and without the GOEXPERIMENT comment.)
func main() {
    if !newLoopSemantics() {
        panic("BUG: newLoopSemantics returned false")
    }
    if got, want := loopDefer(), "cba"; got != want {
        panic("BUG: loopDefer returned: " + got + ", want: " + want)
    }
}
// newLoopSemantics reports whether new range loop var semantics are in effect.
func newLoopSemantics() bool {
    m := make(map[any]bool)
    for i, v := range "abc" {
        m[&i] = true
        m[&v] = true
    }
    switch len(m) {
    case 2:
        return false // old semantics (one var only)
    case 6:
        return true // new semantics (one var per iteration)
    default:
        panic("BUG: inexplicable map size")
    }
}
// loopDefer calls a function that closes over loop variables.
// With new semantics, it returns "cba"; with old, "ccc".
func loopDefer() (res string) {
    for _, c := range "abc" {
        defer func() { res += string(c) }()
    }
    return res
}
```

---

Since Go 1.22 (Q1 2024), [Tapir Liui](https://twitter.com/TapirLiu/) has a detailed page on "[`for` Loop Semantic Changes in Go 1.22: Be Aware of the Impact](https://go101.org/blog/2024-03-01-for-loop-semantic-changes-in-go-1.22.html)".