# What is the best way to create goroutines dynamically?

Tags: go

Sorry if this is a newb question but I'm a newb ;). I have the [following playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ESZRio8nci). How do I create my goroutines dynamically? My first set in the playground works as expected but my second set returns "11" for each value. I can solve it by uncommenting line 38 but that seems kind of like a hack. Is there a more preferred way to create my goroutines dynamically?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func myFunc(i int) int {
    return i
}

func first() {
    firstChannel := make(chan int)
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(0) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(1) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(2) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(3) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(4) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(5) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(6) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(7) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(8) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(9) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(10) }()

    for k := 0; k < 11; k++ {
        select {
        case result := <-firstChannel:
            log.Println(result)
        }
    }
}
func second() {
    secondChannel := make(chan int)
    for j := 0; j < 11; j++ {
        go func() { secondChannel <- myFunc(j) }()
        //time.Sleep(1*time.Millisecond)
    }
    for k := 0; k < 11; k++ {
        select {
        case result := <-secondChannel:
            log.Println(result)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("First set------------------")
    first()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Second set------------------")
    second()
}
```

Result:

```
First set------------------
2009/11/10 23:00:00 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 1
2009/11/10 23:00:00 2
2009/11/10 23:00:00 3
2009/11/10 23:00:00 4
2009/11/10 23:00:00 5
2009/11/10 23:00:00 6
2009/11/10 23:00:00 7
2009/11/10 23:00:00 8
2009/11/10 23:00:00 9
2009/11/10 23:00:00 10
Second set------------------
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
2009/11/10 23:00:01 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)
>
> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.
>
> [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)
>
> Some confusion may arise when using closures with concurrency.
>
> To bind the current value of v to each closure as it is launched, one
>   must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration.
>   One way is to pass the variable as an argument to the closure.
>
> Even easier is just to create a new variable, using a declaration
>   style that may seem odd but works fine in Go.

See [Captured Closure (for Loop Variable) in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692844/captured-closure-for-loop-variable-in-go/26694016#26694016).

Use `j := j`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func myFunc(i int) int {
    return i
}

func first() {
    firstChannel := make(chan int)
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(0) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(1) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(2) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(3) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(4) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(5) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(6) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(7) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(8) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(9) }()
    go func() { firstChannel <- myFunc(10) }()

    for k := 0; k < 11; k++ {
        select {
        case result := <-firstChannel:
            log.Println(result)
        }
    }
}
func second() {
    secondChannel := make(chan int)
    for j := 0; j < 11; j++ {
        j := j
        go func() { secondChannel <- myFunc(j) }()
        //time.Sleep(1*time.Millisecond)
    }
    for k := 0; k < 11; k++ {
        select {
        case result := <-secondChannel:
            log.Println(result)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("First set------------------")
    first()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Second set------------------")
    second()
}
```

Output:

```
First set------------------
2009/11/10 23:00:00 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 1
2009/11/10 23:00:00 2
2009/11/10 23:00:00 3
2009/11/10 23:00:00 4
2009/11/10 23:00:00 5
2009/11/10 23:00:00 6
2009/11/10 23:00:00 7
2009/11/10 23:00:00 8
2009/11/10 23:00:00 9
2009/11/10 23:00:00 10
Second set------------------
2009/11/10 23:00:01 0
2009/11/10 23:00:01 1
2009/11/10 23:00:01 2
2009/11/10 23:00:01 3
2009/11/10 23:00:01 4
2009/11/10 23:00:01 5
2009/11/10 23:00:01 6
2009/11/10 23:00:01 7
2009/11/10 23:00:01 8
2009/11/10 23:00:01 9
2009/11/10 23:00:01 1
```

Answer (score 8):

With the loop

```
for j := 0; j < 11; j++ {
    go func() { secondChannel <- myFunc(j) }()
    //time.Sleep(1*time.Millisecond)
}
```

you create a closure, and the `j` variable becomes shared between your `second()` function and the functions you create inside the loop that runs in separate go routines.(See e.g. [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)) - so there's a race condition when referring to the `j` variable.

The go routines might not start executing before the loop is finished, and then the will all see the j variable as it is at the end of the loop.

You can fix this by making each go routine refer to a separate variable:

```
for j := 0; j < 11; j++ {
    arg := j
    go func() { secondChannel <- myFunc(arg) }()
    //time.Sleep(1*time.Millisecond)
}
```

Now the closure created by the func() in the loop refers to the `arg` variable, which will be separate for each iteration.

Or you can pass it by copying the variable to an argument of your func():

```
for j := 0; j < 11; j++ {
    go func(arg int) { secondChannel <- myFunc(arg) }(j)
    //time.Sleep(1*time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: I really hate having to choose between two very solid answers so I based it purely on time...It looks like you were beaten just slightly by @PeterSO. I upvoted you. Thanks!

Comment: I like passing it as an arg, because it makes clear that the inner variable is related to the `func` literal, instead of leaving the reader looking at a potentially-mysterious declaration.