# Enclosed Variable Overridden In Loop

Tags: pointers, go

I am trying to build an array of functions that contain an enclosed variable (in this case a string) but I was getting some unexpected output. I figure the reason I am getting this output is because the func literal being appended is actually a pointer to code that is being changed after each iteration.

Is there a way to `new()` or `make()` a function type so that `append()` will get a different function instance per iteration instead?

```
package main

import "log"

var functions []func()

func main() {
    for _, s := range [...]string{"goodbye", "cruel", "world"} {
        functions = append(functions, func() {
            log.Println(s)
        })
    }
    for _, f := range functions {
        f()
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
2014/11/23 18:13:16 world
2014/11/23 18:13:16 world
2014/11/23 18:13:16 world
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop uses the same instance of the variable `s`, so each closure shares that single variable. To bind the current value of `s` to each closure as it is launched, one must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration. For example,

```
package main

import "log"

var functions []func()

func main() {
    for _, s := range [...]string{"goodbye", "cruel", "world"} {
        s := s // create new s
        functions = append(functions, func() {
            log.Println(s)
        })
    }
    for _, f := range functions {
        f()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 goodbye
2009/11/10 23:00:00 cruel
2009/11/10 23:00:00 world
```

References:

[What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)

[Captured Closure (for Loop Variable) in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692844/captured-closure-for-loop-variable-in-go/26694016)

Comment: Interesting. So it is actually the scope of the iterator itself rather than the function?