# Why do these two for loop variations give me different behavior?

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, go, closures, slice

I'm seeing different behavior in my program that's tied to this particular loop in my program but I'm not sure I understand why it's behaving the way it is.

```golang
//global variable
var cmds = []string {
    "create",
    "delete",
    "update",
}

func loop1() {

    actions := make(map[string]func())

    for _, cmd := range cmds {
        actions[cmd] = func() {
            fmt.Println(cmd)
        }
    }
    for _, action := range actions {
        action()
    }
}
func loop2() {

    actions := make(map[string]func())

    for i, cmd := range cmds {
        command := cmds[i]
        actions[cmd] = func() {
            fmt.Println(command)
        }
    }
    for _, action := range actions {
        action()
    }
}
```

The output for `loop1()` is

```
update
update
update
```

The output for `loop2()` is

```
delete
update
create
```

I went looking on the [internet](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16) and read the following

> When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration. The first is the index, and the second is a copy of the element at that index

It says a copy, so does that mean it returns a copy of the string but it's really a pointer to variable `cmd`? In which case any references to `cmd` will by the end of the loop all actually reference the last element in the array, e.g. `update`? Does this mean that elements of an array should always be referenced by their index when using the `range` method, and what's the use case for using the element it returns since it's always updating the pointer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Captured Closure (for Loop Variable) in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692844/captured-closure-for-loop-variable-in-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `loop1()` is that you store a function literal in the `actions` map that references the **loop variable** `cmd`. There is only one instance of this loop variable, so when after the loop you call the functions stored in the `actions` map, all will refer to this single loop variable (which is kept because the functions / closures still have a reference to it), but its value *at the time of execution* will be the last value set by the `for` loop, which is the last value in the `cmds` slice (that is, `"update"`, so you'll see `"update"` printed 3 times).

An easy workaround is to make a copy of this loop variable, so each iteration, each function literal will have its own copy, which is "detached" from the loop variable:

```
func loop1() {
    actions := make(map[string]func())

    for _, cmd := range cmds {
        cmd2 := cmd
        actions[cmd] = func() {
            fmt.Println(cmd2) // Refer to the detached, copy variable!
        }
    }
    for _, action := range actions {
        action()
    }
}
```

With this, output of `loop1()` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TZEsDyFMfz)):

```
update
create
delete
```

This it's not an issue of the `for ... range`, it's because the closures refer to the same variable, and you don't use the value of the variable right away, only after the loop. And when you print the value of this variable, all print the same, last value of it.

Also see this possible duplicate: [Golang: Register multiple routes using range for loop slices/map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044245/golang-register-multiple-routes-using-range-for-loop-slices-map/44045012#44045012)

Comment: Ok so it's tied to the fact that we're using closures not anything necessarily to do with the `range` operation

Comment: @sreya Yes, it's not an issue of the `for ... range`, it's because the closures refer to the same variable, and when you print the value of this variable, all print the same, last value of it.

Comment: Or for cleaner code, just pass the variable to the closure as an argument: `actions[cmd] = func(cmd string) { fmt.Println(cmd) } (cmd)`

Comment: @Adrian In general yes, but in this case the command is a function type with no parameters, so it's much more inconvenient to use it that way.