# Background threads in ASP.NET - what mechanism is best?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

First off, I know the "correct" answer is don't do background threads in a ASP.NET web app. We have a good reason for doing it this way so please accept the postulate that it makes sense for our use case.

Our background processing is generally CPU bound (can be IO bound at times). And generally will take between 2 seconds and 2 minutes (and occasionally longer, as much as an hour). We will limit the number of background workers to 1.5x the number of cores on the server.

I also assume that it's best to use an existing thread pool in the ASP.NET environment. My code will limit the number of threads, but I'm guessing it's best to pull from the existing pool.

Which then leads to the question, what is the best way to create the threads?

1. ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
2. HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()
3. Task.Run()
4. Something else?

And do HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem() & Task.Run() come out of the ASP.NET thread pool?

Comment: [`QueueUserWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8) is the only way to register the long-running transaction with the hosting environment so it doesn't kill your threads when the app pool recycles.

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is just the older implementation (introduced in .NET 1.1) of doing the same job as Task.Run (introduced in .NET 4.5). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38883705/4308286

Comment: @JohnWu I thought QueueBackgroundWorkItem() was the only way to delay shutdown until the threads complete? And I believe it only delays for up to 15 seconds.

Comment: @DavidThielen Ugh yeah I mean QueueBackgroundWorkItem (and that is in fact where my link will take you), I just mistyped. You are correct sir.

Comment: @JohnWu No problem. I appreciate bouncing this stuff off of you.