# Simple syntax to create a record/tuple to pass few objects as a single parameter?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Consider use case: I need to pass a parameter to `QueueUserWorkItem`:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
{
    var item = o as MyObject;
},
item);
```

Then requirements changed and I now need to pass 2 objects. So I would have to write something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
{
    var items = o as Tuple<MyObject,MyObject2>;
},
new Tuple<MyObject,MyObject2>(item1, item2));
```

**Is there a cleaner way to achieve this in C# 9+ ?**

Comment: wouldn't this work?  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o1,o2)) =>

Comment: cmon guys. its .NET api - how can i change it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_ThreadPool_QueueUserWorkItem__1_System_Action___0____0_System_Boolean_) if your target framework has it. Then you can do:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(args => {
    var first = args.Item1; // it's of type string already
    var second = args.Item2; // this is int
}, ("a", 1), false);
```

Or:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(args => {
    var first = args.first; // it's of type string already
    var second = args.second; // this is int
}, (first: "a", second: 1), false); // name parameters here instead of using Item1 Item2
```

And in single parameter case you don't need to cast type from object (this overload accepts generic `Action<T>` delegate).

Answer (score 0):

You can always leverage [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428617/2501279) in C# lambdas and ingore passing parameter completely:

```
var item1 = ...;
var item2 = ...;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(item1);
    Console.WriteLine(item2);
});
```

Also personally I would consider switching to `Task.Run` instead of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` (though there should be some considiration due to some [differences in behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45810755/2501279)).

Comment: I always thought that in this case item1/2 in the outer scope can be tainted by another thread cutting in between.. this is why i actually am passing the object as a parameter rather than using it inside the delegate.. can you provide definitive proof its not the case?

Comment: @BoppityBop it depends on what do you mean by "tainted" and "another thread cutting in between".  AFAIK you can have only the usual problems with closures - if local variable  is modified after being captured by the action (the infamous [for/foreach closure behaviour difference after C# 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35365350/2501279)).

Comment: yes - I am passing object as a param instead of using closures because I am convinced that its value can be modified in another thread before it is used in this thread.. so in short words - I want solution without using closures.. Ill edit the question.

Comment: @BoppityBop can you please share some code that can have such problem? Also i hugely depends on what `item1` and `item2` are and how they are used.