# How do I iterate through a dynamically valued dictionary in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I am trying to spawn threads in a for each loop using a copy of the value in a dict.

My initial understanding was that the `foreach` would create a new scope, and led to:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "sr1", "1" }, { "sr2", "2" } };
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> record in Dict) {
    new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(record.Value);
    }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
}
```

which writes

```
1
2
2
2
```

instead of (expected):

```
1
2
1
2
```

So I tried cloning the kvp in the foreach:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> tmp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(record.Key, record.Value);
```

but that renders the same result.

I've also tried it with `System.Parallel.ForEach` but that seems need values that are not dynamic, which is a bit of a train smash for my dictionary.

How can I iterate through my Dictionary with threads?

Comment: I can't see how the code you've given would work at all, given that you don't start the timer... and you've got 2 entries in your dictionary, not the 4 you're printing out. If you can create a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would really help.

Comment: First, why would it write 1/2/1/2 when all dictio entries have Value of 1? Then, why'd you try to put two dictio entries with the same "sr" key? It would immediatelly throw..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Whoops, the 2nd sr was meant to be "2" to demonstrate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach) -- even if not exactly the duplicate, the **question** under that link perfectly describes the problem and its cause and effects. Please check it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is [closure over your lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), the way to fix is is to add a local variable inside the for loop

```
Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "sr1", "1" }, { "sr2", "2" } };
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> record in Dict) {

    var localRecord = record;
    new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(localRecord.Value);
    }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
}
```

What is happening in your version is it captures the variable `record` not the **value of the variable** record. So when the timer runs the 2nd time it uses the "current value" of `record` which is the 2nd element in the array.

Behind the scenes this is what is kinda what is happening in your version of the code.

```
public void MainFunc()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "sr1", "1" }, { "sr2", "2" } };
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> record in Dict) {

        _recordStored = record;
        new System.Threading.Timer(AnnonFunc, null, TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
    }
}

private KeyValuePair<string, string> _recordStored;

private void AnnonFunc()
{
    Console.WriteLine(_recordStored.Value);
}
```

See how when your function ran it for the first itteration had the correct version of `_recordStored`, but after `_recordStored` got overwritten it will only show the last set value. By creating a local variable it does not do that overwriting.

A way to imagine it (I am not sure how I could represent it in a code example) is it creates `_recordStored1` the first loop, `_recordStored2` the 2nd loop, and so on. The function uses the correct version of `_recordStored#` for when it calls the the function.

Comment: FYI: [Is there a reason for reuse of the variable in a foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach) describes all problems with foreach's autovariable quite well and in-depth, and even comes with EricLippert's comments ;)

Comment: Pointer + Concurrency bugs are fun! Why the hell do I need to specify a type for the foreach if its just a pointer anyway though?

Comment: Alternatively... one could just use C#5 were IIRC they changed the behaviour of foreach :)  "In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx

Comment: @Alex The reason you have to specify the type is because Dictionary only implments `IEnumerable` not `IEnumberable<TKey,TValue>`, why it does not do it, I do not know. Also it is not a pointer, pointers are a very different thing and use the `IntPtr` datatype.