# Why does this output 333 not 0112 at Array.ForEach?

Tags: c#

Why the below code ouput 333 not 012?
I think the code is so simple and I check and check and double check, triple check, can not get answer yet. Any one can help me?

```
Action[] tmp = new Action[3];

for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
{
    tmp[i] = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
}

Array.ForEach(tmp, m => m());

Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to:

```
Action[] tmp = new Action[3];

for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    tmp[i] = () => Console.WriteLine(j);
}

Array.ForEach(tmp, m => m());

Console.Read();
```

The reason is closure is nest

More detailed information please see those links:
[Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach)
http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Comment: Thank you very much. I immediately get the correct result use your code. Even your links are the same as other one provide. But you are the one give the code. So I accept your answer. But I also thank other guys.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because there is only *one* `i` variable in the original code as `for` does *not* introduce a new variable "each loop" and the *same* variable is closed over in all the closures! As such, the *same* (`i`) variable is assigned the last value (3) before any of the functions are executed after the loop.

Compare with the following code which ensures a *new* variable to bind in each closure (this is one rare case where I use underscores for a local variable to show "something funny" is happening):

```
for (int _i = 0; _i < tmp.Length; _i++)
{
    int i = _i; // NEW/fresh variable, i, introduced each loop
    tmp[i] = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This behavior (and complaints against) is discussed in detail in [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach) - `for` and `foreach` have this same "issue" in C#4 and before, which is "fixed" for `foreach` in C#5.

> I think it is fair to say that all regret that decision. This is one of the worst "gotchas" in C#, and we are going to take the breaking change to fix it. In C# 5 the foreach loop variable will be logically inside the body of the loop, and therefore closures will get a fresh copy every time. - Eric Lippert

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Oh, yes. Thanks. I forgot to change all occurrences of the original `i`.