# IndexOutOfRangeException Occurred while executing forloop

Tags: c#, .net

```
IEnumerable<char> query = "Not what you might expect";
string vowels = "aeiou";
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
query = query.Where (c => c != vowels[i]);
foreach (char c in query) Console.Write (c);
```

Exception occurs **IndexOutOfRangeException**. Why this exception occurs every thing looks fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

```
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
{
char vowel = vowels[i];
query = query.Where (c => c != vowel);
}
```

This works fine, what is the difference between these codes. kindly, share the details.

Comment: I don't want the solution of this problem, i need the reason why it happens.

Comment: `i` is captured and being mutated, hence it is out of range after the for loop when you realise `query`

Comment: If only the compiler had a warning for this, this is a problem in the design on C#!!!    Everyone hits the trap at some point.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because

1. IEnumerables are lazy.
2. the value of `i` is not captured.

The `.Where` queries are only actually evaluated when you start printing the output, at which point `i == 5`, leading to the index out of bounds exception.

---

To show more clearly what's going on, below are equivalent queries for each iteration of the loop (Note that `query` always refers to the original query):

```
i = 0;
query.Where(c => c != vowels[i]);

i = 1;
query.Where(c => c != vowels[i]).Where(c => c != vowels[i]);

i = 2;
query.Where(c => c != vowels[i]).Where(c => c != vowels[i]).Where(c => c != vowels[i]);

...
```

See how all queries refer to the same value for `i`? After the final iteration, `i` is incremented one more time, which causes the loop to stop. But now `i == 5`, which is not a valid index anymore!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using IEnumerable, just add .ToList() or .ToArray() to your where clause, it will work

```
        IEnumerable<char> query = "Not what you might expect";
        string vowels = "aeiou";
        IEnumerable<char> result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
            query = query.Where(c => c != vowels[i]).ToList(); // or .ToArray()
        foreach (char c in query) Console.Write(c);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

change the name of your variable `query` in this line

`query = query.Where (c => c != vowels[i]);`

Comment: I am not finding the solution why exception occurs.
Thank You