# What's the difference between for and foreach in respect to closure

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, lambda, closures

The demo code has some problems.

```
var values = new List<int>() { 100, 110, 120 };  
var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();  

foreach(var v in values)   
    funcs.Add( ()=>v );  

foreach(var f in funcs)   
    Console.WriteLine(f());
```

> Most people expect it to be 100 / 110 / 120. It is in fact 120 / 120 / 120.

but the result in vs2015 & .net 4.5.1 will **output 100 / 110 / 120, not 120 / 120 / 120**.

And when I test the code as follows, there are some differences between `for` and `foreach`

```
var values = new List<int> {100, 110, 120};

var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
foreach (var v in values)
    funcs.Add(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        return v;
    } );

foreach (var f in funcs)
    Console.WriteLine(f());

//will throw exception
for (int i=0;i<values.Count;i++)
    funcs.Add(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
        return values[i];
    });

foreach (var f in funcs)
    Console.WriteLine(f());
```

**Who can give me some more detail between `for` and `foreach` in `closures`?**

Comment: You may want to read part 2 including the update http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-two/ . "We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The for loop will not be changed. We return you now to our original article."

Comment: did you saw the update note at the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of an unfortunate decision that was later regretted by the C# team. A breaking change introduced by C# 5 finally changed that behavior. [Quoting Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach):

> In C# 5 the foreach loop variable will be logically inside the body of the loop, and therefore closures will get a fresh copy every time.

Before C# 5, the closures all referenced the **same** variable binding. Therefore, the output was the same for all invocations because they were all accessing the latest value of the same variable.

Starting with C# 5, however, a **new** variable binding is created for each iteration. This is the behavior that was most likely intended by the programmer.

Comment: Its also worth noting that in a for loop it clearly must use the same variable for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Chris Well, it's not that it *must*, it's just that it seems clear that it ought to, from the syntax.  They *could* create a copy of the variable on each iteration if they wanted to.