# Pass value to anonymous function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following call:

```
GameSmart.HighScores.Load(Order.Descending, (HighScoresLoadedResponse response) => {
    foreach(Score score in response.data.scores){
        GameSmart.GetImage(score.avatar, (Sprite sprite) => {
            print(score.score);
        });
    }
});
```

In my `foreach`, can I somehow pass the value of `score` to the anonymous function to be used when the anonymous function gets executed? What I have now always displays the last value in the `Score` array every time the anonymous function executes.

Here is the definition of `GetImage`

```
public static void GetImage(string url, Action<Sprite> onComplete = null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I believe this should work:

```
GameSmart.HighScores.Load(Order.Descending, (HighScoresLoadedResponse response) => {
    foreach(Score score in response.data.scores){
        var scoreRef = score;
        GameSmart.GetImage(score.avatar, (Sprite sprite) => {
            print(scoreRef.score);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: that looks like it works. Why do I have to assign it to a new variable?

Comment: the `foreach` shorthand hides the fact that it's declaring `Score score` outside of the loop. With a variable *inside* the loop, the closures each treat it as a different variable because the scope is restarted each time through. I think a better explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy score to a local variable inside the foreach loop in C# versions before 5.0 . See this question for an explanation of the design change [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach)