# How can I run twice a function at the same time from one class? C#

Tags: c#

When run conflict between class variables!

```
private myClass[] arrayms = new myClass[5];

foreach (myClass ms in arrayms) {
  if (ms.ScheduleState)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ms.Start());
}
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting? Also, you create an array with 5 "slots", but it looks like you do not put any objects in them before calling `foreach`. So `foreach` simply falls through because `arrayms` is empty.

Comment: I got a text summary, Classes are object. program do not have error, but only conflict variables when run.

Comment: I apologize for my language ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I got a text summary, Classes are object. program do not have error, but only conflict variables when run. –

I don't understand "conflict variables". But the rest seems to fit what I described in my previous comment. i.e. the array is empty when calling `foreach`. So maybe this:

```
for (int i=0; i < ms.Length; i++) {
  arrayms[i] = new MyClass();
}

// ScheduleState must somehow get set, then:

foreach (myClass ms in arrayms) {
  if (ms.ScheduleState)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ms.Start());
}
```

**edit**

> what does Task.Factory.StartNew(..) do? Its name StartNew implies that a new object is created and started. But an anonymous method that starts an existing object is passed. So are we actually starting two things here?

if this (comment, below) is not the problem then maybe it's the [infamous scope problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8898925/463206) when calling LINQ in a loop:

```
foreach (myClass ms in arrayms) {
  MyClass workAround = ms;   // must set "ms" to a loop-scoped variable.
                             // why? the answer is TL;DR

  if (workAround.ScheduleState)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => workAround.Start());
```

**end edit**

Comment: When we execute starttask function from myclass class several times, my class variables will be disturbed.

Comment: what does `Task.Factory.StartNew(..)` do? Its name `StartNew` implies that a new object is created and started. But an anonymous method that starts an existing object is passed. So are we actually starting two things here?

Answer (score 0):

How can I run Several from a function at the same time from one class? C#
When run _StartTask() conflict between myClass variables and log result messy

```
private myClass[] arrayms = new myClass[5];
public void _TasksClassCreator()
{
     foreach (var ms in arrayms )
     {
          ms.ScheduleName = SName;
          .
          .
          .
     }
}
public void _StartTask()
{
    foreach (myClass ms in arrayms) 
    {
      if (ms.ScheduleState)
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ms.Start());
    }
}

public sealed class myClass
{
    public void Start()
    {
        _TBTask();
    }
    private void _TBTask()
    {
         while(true)
         {
              ...//Conflict here
              // this function always running and reporting result...
              //log here
         }
    }

    private string _ScheduleName;

    public string ScheduleName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ScheduleName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ScheduleName = value;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```