# Why does this task-generating loop never stop?

Tags: c#, task

Very simple scenario. I am running a tight loop, generating tasks with each iteration. (Don't ask why.)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
        Task.Run(() => WriteHelloAsync(i));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static Task WriteHelloAsync(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {x}!");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I can see in the console that it writes the iteration number incrementally. However, when it reaches the target 1 million, it just keeps on going.

[image]

But why?

Comment: Here's another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach

Answer (score 2):

This is the [classic loop-variable closure problem in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899347/424129).

Your loop does stop at a million.

After it stops at a million, you make some large number of calls to `WriteHelloAsync(i)`.

You're passing `i` to all of them. That lambda you're passing to `Task.Run()` isn't creating a new copy of `i` that holds the value `i` *had* at the time of that particular call to `Task.Run()`. They all have the same `i`, whose value keeps changing until the loop ends.

On my machine here, the first number I see is well into six digits, meaning that's the value of `i` the first time a task actually gets around to calling `WriteHelloAsync()`. Very shortly thereafter, it starts doing the million-million-million thing you see.

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
    {
        //  The scope of j is limited to the loop block.
        //  For each new iteration, there is a new j. 
        var j = i;
        Task.Run(() => WriteHelloAsync(j));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

@Gigi points out that this will also work with a `foreach` rather than `for`:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1000))
{
    Task.Run(() => WriteHelloAsync(i));
}
```

Comment: Closures are magic. Can you mention the mechanism that determines _why_ the variable is reused?

Comment: It's a closure. I don't understand. There it is. It's `i`. There's one `i`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: that's not really helpful. There's one `j`, too.

Comment: @JacobKrall There's a million `j`s. Run the code.

Comment: I thought I had mastered closures. Always grateful to learn something new!

Comment: Thing is, I was under the (wrong) assumption that you could do what I did because the integer is passed by value, so a copy would be made.

Comment: Actually, in the answer you referred to, Lippert said that this was going to be fixed with C# 5. I wonder what happened with that?

Comment: @Gigi That's actually a good question. You might [search his blog](https://ericlippert.com) and his answers here -- or [contact him directly](https://ericlippert.com/about-eric-lippert/) if you don't find anything.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I see it's explained in the comments of that answer. It was fixed in VS2012, but only when using `foreach`. `for` loops will still exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: @Gigi Dang! Now I'm learning something new!