# Pass a constant copy of the iterator for Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my program I currently have a structure similar to this:

```
for (int i=0; i<MyCollection.Count; i++)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        DoStuffWith(MyCollection[i]);
        DoEvenMoreStuffWith(MyCollection[i]);
    });
}
```

It does not work properly because functions `DoStuffWith()` and `DoEvenMoreStuffWith()` take more time to complete than `i++`, hence one of these will usually modify the wrong element of the collection.

I know I can't do `int a = i` before the `Task.Factory` because it's gonna be the same, really.

How do I make sure each thread works with their own index exclusively?

P.S.: Sorry, I tried looking for an answer here but I don't even know how to google it properly. I know it's something that has to do with reference types and value types, but I've never used them around `Task.Factory` before.

Comment: `I know I can't do int a = i before the Task.Factory because it's gonna be the same, really.` is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: but the next iteration will overwrite `a` again, will it not?

Comment: Each iteration is its own scope, and thus will have its own locally-scoped variable.

Comment: @Anver exactly. The difference with `i` is that it exists outside the scope of a single iteration.

Comment: Do you even need the index? Why not use a for each instead. Also recommend using a thread pool not a new thread for each.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I done goofed again. Will try it now, thanks.

Comment: @john yeah, I was helping Torlan understand your comment. :)

Comment: @Anver I know, thank you. I'd been writing my own explanation when your comment came in, so added the last part to complete it :)

Comment: Well multithreading was always a wonky experience for me. So I keep messing up what constitutes the context of operation for a task. Running a multithreaded program always feels like a ride on an orc-made spacecraft. ITS ABOUT TO BREAK OMIGOSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a **standard** `for` loop, you can keep a local copy of the variable within the closure of the loop body (just as you suggested was not possible), and this closure will be captured by the body of your deferred code.

So:

```
for (int i=0; i<MyCollection.Count; i++)
{
    var a = i;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        DoStuffWith(MyCollection[a]);
        DoEvenMoreStuffWith(MyCollection[a]);
    });
}
```

However, there is a better way.

Recently(ish), [the c# language was changed to close over the loop variable in `foreach` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899347/14357).

So, unless you're stuck with 2012-era tooling, now you can:

```
foreach(var item in MyCollection)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        DoStuffWith(item);
        DoEvenMoreStuffWith(item);
    });
}
```

without this issue happening.

As an aside, do you know the [difference between `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)? You should do.

Comment: Thank you for summarizing it! Foreach doesn't work for me because I don't use all elements so I need to keep track of the indices. I left this detail out because it was immaterial to the question.  And I'll give a poke to that article about Tasks. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: @TorlanDelta I tend to prefer `foreach` because, with the language changes that were made, it went from requiring mutable state to becoming a purer functional construct. While this might not be applicable to your case, I'd filter the collection before iterating if I wanted to deal with a subset.